# IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1 Missing Javascript Libraries Menu in Settings

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea, libraries

I am a bit confused... I have IntellJ IDEA 2017.1 and I am trying to set up some external JS libraries, as per the JetBrains documentation I should go to

> Settings > Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript > Libraries

And from there download the library I need... Except, there is no `Libraries` sub-menu item under JavaScript.

[image: Missing Menu]

I have the JavaScript Support plugin enabled, so I really don't understand why it's missing.

Any thoughts?

EDIT:
Here is the screen of the menu I use to access Settings while I am NOT in a project.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have opened default project settings (`File | Default Settings`). Default settings is a template for new project, there is no way to set up libraries there. You should have opened your project preferences instead (`File | Settings` on Windows/Linux or `Idea | Preferences` on OSX)

Comment: No I opened Settings from the Welcome screen... `Configure` dropdown and then `Settings`

Comment: Added the screen of the menu as well... just for clarity.

Comment: Only default settings are available from Welcome screen, when no projects are opened. See what's written at the top of your first screen: `Languages & Frameworks > JavaScript For default project`

Comment: Yep you are right... Thanks... I never noticed that.